# I click just outside an object and it automatically selects the closest vertex or edge, why God?

Tags: selection-tools, select, mouse

Out of nowhere, whenever I hit the mouse button next to a vertex, edge, or face, it automatically selects, without the need to click right on it - so when I try to select multiple vertexes that are close to each other, it's just not possible, 'cause it keeps selecting the closest vertex.

[image]

In the GIF you can see I click just outside the object and it selects the closest vertex (it goes the same for edges)

Comment: hello, it's hard to understand, in Blender left click will select the object/vertex in the 3D view

Comment: is it possible that you pressed the W button by accident? just tap it again and it should work as normal again...

Comment: One of the problems is that I actually don't know exactly how to put this problem I'm having into words haha It'd be easier if I could show it in a video or GIF

Comment: I just added a GIF to the text, and also incremented the description a little bit. Thank you guys for the attention!

Comment: From your gif, you are switching between Move tool and the select tool (left tool bar)

Comment: I we click just outside an object it automatically selects the closest vertice, face or edge for everyone

Answer (score 1):

**If we click just outside an object it automatically selects the closest vertice, face or edge for everyone.These are just the default settings of blender. You haven`t accidentally changed any of the settings.**

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Comment: I mean, the problem may just be in my mind then, 'cause I've been using Blender for many months, and just now it's been bugging me, something still feels off lol Well, thanks for showing me that the problem is actually me.